# can't access to website in my server

Tags: authentication, vbscript, asp-classic, web-config

I work in localhost in one platform. 
The flow is:

1. LOGIN.ASP insert my login info (username + password)

in login.asp I have this

```vb
If Session("isAdmin") Then
    Response.Redirect "../default.asp"
Else
    Response.Redirect "../index.asp"
End If
```

although in the server gives me error

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL.
>   Please contact the system administrator. 
>   If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

the url is /common/_loginme.asp 
in this page the code is:

```vb
<%    
Dim username, password
username = Request.Form("username")
password = Request.Form("password")
If username = "" Then Response.Redirect "login.asp?m=Username é obrigatório."
If password = "" Then Response.Redirect "login.asp?m=Password é obrigatório."
%>
<!-- #include file="_db.asp" -->
<%
sqlLogin = "SELECT TOP 1 id, roleId, name FROM Users WHERE isActive = True AND username = '" & CleanStr(username) & "' AND password = '" & CleanStr(password) & "'"
Set RSlogin = Conn.Execute(sqlLogin)
If RSlogin.EOF Then
    Rslogin.Close
    Closeconn
    Response.Redirect "../login.asp?m=Username ou Password incorretas."
Else
    Session("isAdmin") = RSlogin("roleId") = 1
    Session("LoginID") = RSlogin("id")
    Session("Name") = RSlogin("name")
    Rslogin.Close
    Closeconn
    If Session("isAdmin") Then
        Response.Redirect "../default.asp"
    Else
        Response.Redirect "../index.asp"
    End If
End If
RSlogin.Close
Closeconn
%>
<%
Function CleanStr(s)    
    s = Replace(s,"'","")
    s = Replace(s,"<","")
    s = Replace(s,">","")
    s = Replace(s,";","")
    CleanStr = s
End Function
%>
```

Why in local host I run well but it server not?

one more snippet, web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="Login.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you describe is the standard ASP error message, so the user does not get info about the error on the production server.

While this is the desired behaviour, you will have to enable error output, so you can see, what is going wrong.

In IIS settings on your server, choose ASP, open the "Debugging Properties" and enable the option "Send Errors To Browser".

More detailed info [here](http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp) or [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/670853/iis-8-show-classic-asp-errors-in-browser).

This way, you should get more information on what really fails in your production setup.

Comment: the error is  
`ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a' 
Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. 
/Question/common/_db.asp, line 11`

and the db.asp 

`<%
Dim Conn
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Dim ConnectionString
%>
<!--#include file ="DB.INC" -->
<%
    
ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & dbPath
Conn.Open ConnectionString
Sub CloseConn
 Conn.Close
 Set Conn = Nothing
End Sub
%>`

and the db.inc
`<% Dim dbPath : dbPath = "\\server.domain\db\db.mdb"  %>`

Comment: Well, it seems you should install the database provider driver.

Comment: should install **MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0** right?
ADODB.Connection is only the "connection" right? (I'm kinda noob/new)

Comment: That's correct. *ADODB.Connection* is the Wrapper to access your database. I can't help you very much on the JET installation, as I only worked with SQL server connections.